# PHP create an array from mysqli query results

Tags: php, arrays, mysqli, fetch

I have code that stores the results of a mysqli query in an array, but I want to make the code a little more advanced by only storing the results of one column in the array. Here's my code:

```
// Create array of devices that match the current unit in array $unitsarray
$result = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM `department devices` WHERE unit LIKE $unit");

//Fetch all rows in result and store them in an array $rows
$rows = array();
while($row = $result->fetch_row()) {
    $rows[] = $row;
}
```

Comment: Voting to close becaue OP has made no effort to try anything himself - you don't want "to make the code a little more advanced", you want somebody to make it a little more advanced for you

Comment: I have obviously tried, and I can't figure it out, that's why I am asking here.

Comment: Well, if you only want to store one column, you could always just select that column... i.e. `SELECT mycol FROM...`

Comment: What do mean store the results of one column in the array? If you just want one column from your row then select that column in your SQL. How does this make anything **more advanced**?

Comment: @Jon - the code you've posted gives no indication that you've tried anything... tell us what you tried, and we're more likley to spend our time helping

Comment: I tried this: $mysqli->rows[] = $row["devicetoken"];

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ex: If you want column x, You just get the column x from your database so, did you try to change your query;

```
$result = $mysqli->query("SELECT x FROM `department devices` WHERE unit LIKE $unit");
```

Answer (score 0):

What would make your code "more advanced" is to:

1. accept that '->fetch_assoc()` always returns an array of the columns
2. write your own database handler to handle the sort of resultset transformations you want.

The latter is called *abstraction* and is a major reason code libraries are written.